# How much should a programmer know about complexity?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I know that a lot of questions have been asked about the time and space complexity of the algorithms. I have been seeing very complicated things like `O(n)`, `o(n)`, `w(n)` etc

From a programmer's perspective, what all knowledge should be there to make the program more efficient in terms of time(primarily) (as space is not much of a concern now a days).

I see people talking about `O(n)`, should I be only concerned about `O(n)` or are there other things also?

Comment: What you are talking about is Big O Notation.  I recommend Google searching this topic and reading about it.  Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I can read about Big O, but it will not help me in knowing whether only it is relevant in a programmer's job or are other things also relevant. Learning computer science and programming has a little correlation.

Comment: Are you asking if knowing about time and space complexity is important as a programmer? I would say it is crucial.

Comment: No that is not my question, question is how much should I know from a programmers perspective, and please explain the things that I should know.

Comment: What do you mean by how much you should know? Either you know about Big-O notation or you don't. Can you be more specific?

Comment: See, there are many things like Big O, Big Omega, small O etc, so out of these which are the most relevant, and why, what should a programmer know about from a necessity point of view and how much of it and also why?

Comment: I would say big-o is the most relevant, but that is maily because it is the only one I actually use when discussing problems with collegues. Everyone seem to know and understand the big-O notation compared to many of the other notations. However I would still say that knowing about the others is useful for understanding more complex algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

First: Big-O notation and complexities are two different things. Big-O notation is (often) used to simplify the algorithm complexity analysis, but Big-O notation itself has nothing to do with algorithm complexity.

I think you should be able to calculate the complexity of simple algorithms and functions, so you can write efficient code or at least noticed if you code is not efficient and you can look for improvements.

But calculating the complexity of complicated algorithms can be very difficult (or even impossible). This is something for algorithm engineers, not for programmers.

This is only my opinion since this question seams to be primary opinion based.

In most cases we only care about worst case complexity, so we know how bad it can be. For simple algorithms best and worst cases are most likely the same. But we also use amortized complexity (often used in randomized data structures) and average case complexities (e.g. quick sort).

Comment: Why are we only concerned about worst case? For a given data set how can we be sure that 2 algorithms will always take worst case time, not other cases?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat This sounds like a new question, so I extend my answer a little bit. If you want to know more you should open a new question.

Comment: Ok, I shall add a new question.